# Why isn't fflush allowing my program to switch modes?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw

I have the following C application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    // Create a file.
    FILE *filePointer = fopen("deleteme.txt", "w+");
    if (filePointer == NULL) {
        printf("Operation failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Write "Test" to the file.
    if (fputs("Test", filePointer) == EOF) {
        printf("Operation failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Seek to the beginning.
    if (fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        printf("Operation failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Read the character "T".
    if (fgetc(filePointer) == EOF) {
        printf("Operation failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Flush streams.
    fflush(filePointer);
    // Write "esting" to the file.
    if (fputs("esting", filePointer) == EOF) { // <--- Fails here.
        printf("Operation failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Operation succeeded.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am running it under the Windows operating system with:

- Visual Studio Code 1.48.2
- C/C++ (Extension for Visual Studio Code) 0.29.0
- Code Runner (Extension for Visual Studio Code) 0.11.0
- MinGW (mingw32-base) 2013072200

The code I've linked above fails on the call to `fputs("esting", filePointer)`. Why is that? Looking at [documentation online](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/?kw=fflush), it says:

> In files open for update (i.e., open for both reading and writing),
> the stream shall be flushed after an output operation before
> performing an input operation. This can be done either by
> repositioning (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) or by calling explicitly fflush

As you can see in the code above, since I have opened the file in update mode `w+`, I am calling `fflush` explicitly before I call `fputs`. I was hoping that this would allow me to switch modes so that I can perform a write after reading, or did I misinterpret the documentation? I know that the code above will work if I replace `fflush` with a call to `fseek` instead (swapping `fflush` for `fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_CUR)` seems to solve this problem), but why does it not work when using `fflush`?

Comment: The `fflush` should only be necessary when reading after writing, and not like here, when writing after reading. But the actual problem here is probably related to the fact that `fgetc` moves the file pointer more than 1 byte, calling `ftell` afterwards gives me 4.

Comment: @ssbssa For me, `ftell` returns a value of `1` after the call to `fgetc`. This is as expected, because `char` is 1 byte in my environment. It looks like you called `ftell` after `fflush`, which seems to advance the stream position to the end, in which case it does return `4`.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows. You're right, after `fgetc` it returns 1, but after `fflush` it returns 4, weird.

Comment: @ssbssa Yes, and also...since we are in write and update mode `w+`, I am expecting that `fflush` would allow us to switch from reading to writing, as the documentation says. In update mode, your first operation of reading or writing places you in that mode, and you need to switch modes afterwards for the opposite operation to be allowed. `fseek` does work as the documentation says, but I am wondering why `fflush` does not.

Comment: I think I found now the relevant documentation, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019): `However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function.`

Comment: @ssbssa Nice find!